# Check whether two discs overlap in C

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

I have to output the number of non-overlapping discs. It is said that two discs overlap if at least one point overlaps (they touch). The condition for overlapping that i use: [image]
The first input is the number of discs that i should read from the keyboard. The next n lines of input contain three integers, the x, y coordinates and the radius of that circle.
The problem is that my output is not correct, i tried all kinds of conditions for checking whether the discs overlap, but every time i'm getting different results. For example, when inputting the following data, the output is 5, when it should be 3.

> 10
>   0 0 5
>   1 7 1
>   6 0 3
>   -12 9 10
>   8 8 6
>   5 3 4
>   3 2 2
>   7 -10 7
>   3 15 2
>   -9 -7 7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int **readDiscs(int n) //reading discs data into array
{
    int **discs = (int **) calloc(n, sizeof(int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        discs[i] = (int *) calloc(3, sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            scanf("%d", &discs[i][j]);
    }
    return (discs);
}

int checkOverlap(int **discs, int length)
{
    int *overlaps = (int *) calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    int k = 0, R1, R2, X1, X2, Y1, Y2;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
        {
            R1 = discs[i][2];
            R2 = discs[j][2];
            X1 = discs[i][0];
            X2 = discs[j][0];
            Y1 = discs[i][1];
            Y2 = discs[j][1];
            if (sqrt(pow(X2 - X1, 2) + pow(Y2 - Y1, 2)) <= (R1 + R2))   //if the distance is less or equal to radius,
                overlaps[i] = 1;                                        //then they overlap or at least touch
        }
    for (int f = 0; f < length; f++)
        if (overlaps[f] == 0)
            k++;
    free(overlaps);
    return (k);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int **discs;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    discs = readDiscs(n);
    printf("%d\n", checkOverlap(discs, n));
    free(discs);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak: You call `calloc` multiple times for `discs`, but you only call `free` once.

Comment: Basic [debugging techniques](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/): (1) print the data that is read to make sure the program sees what you think it is seeing; (2) print the results of the key calculations — in this case, print the distance between the centres and the sum the sums of the radii and inspect.  That'll help you determine what's going wrong.   Basic coding technique: check file opens and read operations — they fail on occasion.

Comment: You can <s>optimize</s> fix your search by noting that if `i` and `j` overlap, you can record that for both disks.  So, when the overlap condition is true, you should have two assignments.  In fact, I think this is the cause of your problem.  Suppose disks 1 and 4 (of 4 total) overlap.  You record that 1 overlaps (with 4), but you never record that 4 overlaps with 1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, your idea solved the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, isn't the free function freeing the whole memory segment allocated for that pointer?

Comment: You need to free each of the 3-integer arrays you allocated, as well as (and before) freeing the array of pointers.  Count the `calloc()` calls; count the `free()` calls.  The number should be the same, but isn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, so as to conclude, i'm missing n free calls for each row of the discs array.

Comment: For each call to `malloc`, `callor`, `realloc` (or other function using them) you have to match it with a `free`.

Comment: Succinctly, yes (you are missing `n` calls to `free()`, one for each of the arrays pointed to by the pointers in the `discs` array in the `main()` program).  If you've not yet come across [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and you're on a platform that supports it, then you should become acquainted with it.  It will tell you when and where you're leaking memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix your search by noting that if `i` and `j` overlap, you should record that for both disks.  So, when the overlap condition is true, you should have two assignments.

Suppose disks 1 and 4 (of 4 total) overlap, but neither disk 2 nor disk 3 overlaps with any disk.  You record that 1 overlaps (with 4), but you never record that 4 overlaps with 1.